# conda env interferring wth python-env

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, ubuntu-14.04, anaconda

I am attempting to follow this tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-14-04

and see that I run into a problem similar to this one (urllib3 not importing) https://github.com/certbot/certbot/issues/2108

I had installed and used conda actively in this Ubuntu environment and suspect that this is causing virtual env to look in the wrong places for urllib3?

Basically:

How can I remove all of conda's interference? Deletion of conda from env completely? Removing path? Which path variable should I change?

Comment: Did you find any solution on this yet? I am facing the same problem...